# Import code works fine on local computer but gives error on aws

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

**models.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

from subject.models import Subject
from core.utils import generate_file_name


def file_upload_path(instance, filename):
    # File will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT / user_<id>/<filename>
    name = instance.slug + ".zip"
    file_path = generate_file_name()
    return 'project_{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(file_path, instance.slug, name)


def image_upload_path(instance, filename):
    # File will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT / user_<id>/<filename>
    if instance.project_image1 == filename:
        filename = "image_1.png"
    elif instance.project_image2 == filename:
        filename = "image_2.png"
    elif instance.project_image3 == filename:
        filename = "image_3.png"
    return 'project_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.slug, filename)


class Project(models.Model):
    """This is model for project"""

    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    technologies = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=99, decimal_places=2)
    subject = models.ManyToManyField(
        Subject, related_name="projects")
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    project_image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_path)
    project_image2 = models.ImageField(
        blank=True, null=True, upload_to=image_upload_path)
    project_image3 = models.ImageField(
        blank=True, null=True, upload_to=image_upload_path)
    project_zip = models.FileField(upload_to=file_upload_path)

    def search_by_id(self, id):
        return self.objects.get(id=id)

    def search_by_slug(self, slug):
        return self.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, generics
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser, MultiPartParser, FileUploadParser

from .models import Project
from .serializers import ProjectSerializer, ProjectListSerializer
from .permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly


class ProjectCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly, ]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)


class ProjectListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)
    serializer_class = ProjectListSerializer
    queryset = Project.objects.all()


class ProjectRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)
    serializer_class = ProjectListSerializer
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "slug"
```

On local computer the line form `.models import Project` works fine
But whey i deploy on aws then it gives error.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://www.compute.amazonaws.com/api/user/login
Django Version: 3.1.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name 'Project' from 'project.models' (/home/ubuntu/project/vtu-project-backend-django/api/project/models.py)
Exception Location: /home/ubuntu/project/vtu-project-backend-django/api/project/views.py, line 4, in <module>
Python Executable:  /home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/vtu-project-backend-django-_DtFEd4z/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/home/ubuntu/project/vtu-project-backend-django/api',
 '/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/vtu-project-backend-django-_DtFEd4z/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/vtu-project-backend-django-_DtFEd4z/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 07 Sep 2020 13:00:24 +0000
```

On local computer, it works fine but when deployed to amazon web services it gives this error and i'm not able to resolve this error. Please help
What is wrong with stack overflow it keeps saying your question is mostly code add more details.

Comment: What command are you using to the run the python program in aws? Since it is relative import, you'll have to specify module name while running the program.

Comment: You probably messed up with some base_path in your settings.py. Make sure paths are correct here. Maybe post the corresponding part of your settings file.